# How to write a wstringstream into a wofstream with wide chars?

Tags: c++

I would like to write a wide char stream into a unicode coded file.

For this, I'm trying this code:

```
std::wstringstream ss;
ss << L"Test";

std::wofstream output(L"C:\\Test.txt", std::ios_base::binary);
output << ss.str();
```

Unfortunately, this writes 4 bytes only, but I would like to get 8 bytes, since "Test" coded with unicode has 8 bytes.

What is my mistake?

I'm using .Net with Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Have you tried `ss << L"Test";` yet? Have you tried `imbue()`'ing a Unicode locale into the `wofstream`? Worse case, you could just use `std::ofstream` instead and `write()` the `wstring` characters to it.